# JS error on IE 9 and 10 - Unable to get property of 1 undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, internet-explorer

I am getting an error only on IE 9 and 10 (I am not supporting anything below IE9) and the site works fine on IE 11 and rest of the browsers.

I am populating timezone info and displaying it on my page but the script gives me an error on aforementioned browser versions.

Here is my JS code

```
populateLocalTimeInfo: function() {
        var days = [sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat],
            weekDayNumber = (new Date).getDay(),
            weekDay = days[weekDayNumber],
            localTime = date.formatFullDate(new Date());

        // Timezone
        var regExp = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
        localTime += ' (' + regExp.exec(new Date)[1] + ')';

        $('#local_time').html(replaceParams(localDateTime, [weekDay, localTime]));
    },
```

The line on which I am getting script error is

```
localTime += ' (' + regExp.exec(new Date)[1] + ')';
```

I am quite not sure why IE 9 and 10 couldn't parse this line of code and throwing unable to get property error. Because of this my page take forever to load the content.

I don't see the same script error on IE 11 and the page loads just fine.

Comment: It's not that they couldn't *parse* the code, it's that running it fails, presumably because `exec` returned `null`. So the question you have to ask is, *why* did `exec` return `null`. To know that, you need to look at what you get from `String(new Date)` on the affected browsers. Basic debugging.

Comment: *"`days = [sun, mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat]`"* Presumably those variables (`sun`, `mon`, and such) are defined somewhere in the code you haven't shown?

Comment: yes days variables are defined in the translation file for e.g var sun = "Sunday" and so on..

Answer (score 2):

Your code relies on `new Date`, converted to a string, having parentheses in it, like this example from Chrome:

```
Thu Apr 24 2014 08:50:04 GMT+0100 (BST)
```

But on IE10 (at least in my locale), it doesn't have parentheses:

```
Thu Apr 24 08:50:10 UTC+0100 2014
```

Hence `exec` returning `null` (because there was no match), hence the error.

The exact format of that string [is undefined by the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.5.2):

> 15.9.5.2 `Date.prototype.toString ( )`
>
> This function returns a String value. The contents of the String are implementation-dependent, but are intended to represent the Date in the current time zone in a convenient, human-readable form.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I see that the argument Date is not assignable to parameter type string. However, I am still not sure how to fix the issue. Is there any difference why does it work on IE 11 and not on IE 10?

Comment: *"I see that the argument Date is not assignable to parameter type string."* Huh? *"Is there any difference why does it work on IE 11 and not on IE 10?"* Again, basic debugging: What do you get for `String(new Date)` on IE11? My guess is that it has parentheses in it.

Comment: yes it does have parentheses. Thursday Racing - 10:30 24/04/2014 (FLE Summer Time)